# ajax return image length with loop , check last loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
success: function(f) {
  var thumbnailbox = $("#warpper");
  for (var obj in f) {
    foldersrcname = [];
    //put all folder name to array
    foldersrcname.push(f[obj].name);
    for (var c = 0; c < foldersrcname.length; c++) {
      var temp = "";
      temp += < li class = "image_icon" > < /li>
    }
  }
  thumbnailbox.html(temp);
  var lis = $('#warpper ul li');
  var i = 0;
  lis.each(function() {
    i++;
  });
  var total = lis.length;
  //i need to get last element is been added//
  if (i === total) {
    //remove something
  }
}
```

i had a ajax which will return image src with loop , it will create li and add into #warpper , my question will be how i gonna know the last image src have been added ?

so lets said the return ajax of the foldersrcnname.length is 7 , and the loop is going to continue adding the src into li one by one, how i check when will be the last loop ?

i need to know when the loop finish added the last one so i can remove something.

Comment: Um - if `f` is an array of files, can't you check if `f[obj]` (or `f[obj].name`) exists, and then not add it to array, if it doesn't?

Comment: Please share more information as your problem is not clear;

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var c = 0; c < foldersrcname.length; c++) {
      var temp = "";

      if((c+1==foldersrcname.length){
        temp += < li class = "image_icon last-li">< /li>
      }
      temp += < li class = "image_icon" > < /li>
    }
```

And you can get last `li` using
`$('#warpper ul li.last-li')`

EDIT :

```
$('#warpper ul li.last-li').length
```

Comment: is there anyway i can know the total li ?